# Is there a better way to check if a number should be inside a range, in scalatest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Say I wanna check if the result (an integer) should `>=4` and `<=15`, I can write such assertion in a ScalaTest test:

```
assert(num >= 4)
assert(num <= 15)
```

It works but can be improved in my opinion. Is there any better way to check it in Scalatest?

Comment: Basically you want to check if the number is either 4 or 5, right?

Comment: Why do you need to call `toInt`? That test seems suspect to me.

Comment: Sorry, Let's make it clear

Answer (score 5):

Something like this will work (using `Matchers`):

```
val beWithin4and5 = be >= 4 and be <= 5

value should beWithin4And5
```

Comment: And on one line brackets are needed: `value should (be >= 4 and be <= 5)`

Answer (score 3):

This maybe: `assert(4 to 5 contains res.toInt)`?

Comment: where did you find this syntax, just starting with scala here

Answer (score 2):

You can use a matcher. Checking a range for the numbers you gave don't make much sense but this does for example :

```
numberExample should be (6 +- 1)
```

Here the test will fail if `numberExample` is lower than 5 or greater than 7.

If what you wanted is either 4 or 5 you can do this :

```
numberExample should (equal 4 or 5)
```